# How to successfully exit an Azure Web Job?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure Web Job, and currently the function iself will always complete with a success. However the job itself fails with this error:

```
[11/26/2016 07:12:11 > 462baa: ERR ] Command 'cmd /c ""MyJob.Webjob ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.
cmd /c ""MyJob.Webjob.StuffJob.exe""
[11/26/2016 07:12:11 > 462baa: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
```

What can I do once my function is complete to let the job know it's done instead of sitting idle and timing out?

Here is my Functions' class method. Everything runs fine, but it doesn't properly stop and I don't know how to tell the job when I'm done.

```
[NoAutomaticTrigger()]
        public void ProcessLoanOriginationDocuments(TextWriter log)
        {
            try
            {
                log.WriteLine("Starting  Job");
                _service.DoSomething();
                log.WriteLine("Ending  Job");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: My impression was that you don't need to do anything special, can you share the code?

Comment: have you checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489467/azure-webjob-command-timeout?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can I do once my function is complete to let the job know it's done instead of sitting idle and timing out?

From my experience, we need to set the **WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT** value enough large to let the WebJob be executed completely.

From your description, the azure WebJob stopped may be caused by a website in idle. Please have a try to troubleshoot as following ways:

1. Set the website “Always On”

   > "**Always On**" is not supported if WebApp is in a free Service Plan tier. If the WebApp is in a free tier, please scale up the App Service Plan. Please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview#scale-an-app-service-plan) for more info about how to scale up the App Service Plan.

[image]

2. Add the WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT in the Azure Portal. More Info about WebApp setting please refer to [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs#configuration-settings).

[image]

3. If it is not resolved with above ways, please have a try keep writing out to console to keep the WebJob running.