# Set Azure Triggered WebJob timeout to infinite

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs

We can set the idle timeout for triggered webjobs using this (`WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT`) property in the WebApp Appsettings (in Azure). To set it for 24 hours i now set this property to 86400, but i would rather set the idle time-out to infinite. As that possible? And if so, how? And if not, what is the maximum value?

I am looking for this, because the development/test setups are not used for a while and when we start using it, we don't want to manually start the webjob. Initial start is done in CI after/during release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it seems that the `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT` doesn't have the infinite value and the maximum value, we can set the Idle Timeout to huge numbers as far as possible.

Actually, there is another way is also feasible.  As the [Configuration Settings](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#configuration-settings) says,

> **WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT** - Time in seconds after which we'll abort a
>   running triggered job's process if it's in idle, has no cpu time or
>   output (Only for triggered jobs).

so we could add a heartbeat style Console write every period of time.

For example:

```
//SEE IF THIS HAS BEEN RUNNING FOR MORE THAN 24 HOURS
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartTime).TotalHours >= 24)
                    ThereAreItemsInQueue = false;

                Counter++;
if (Counter % 25 == 0)
   Console.WriteLine("Heartbeat");
```

There are two articles for you to refer to, [1](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/magnetismsolutionscrmblog/archive/2017/05/15/preventing-idle-timeout-in-triggered-azure-webjobs-jobs) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489467/azure-webjob-command-timeout).

Comment: Yes, the console ping brought me to some ideas. I still have the 24 hour idle timeout set, but we also have a continuous webjob running at scheduled times. Rather then pinging the triggered webjob console style, we now use the continuous webjob to drop an empty message in the queue for the triggered job to reset the idle timeout.

Comment: @BobMeijwaard Glad to know the issue has been solved, it sounds good.